# Linux: How to enforce specific permissions on newly created logs which are created by log rotate?

Tags: log-files, logrotate, user-permissions

I've noticed that the mail logs which are being created in `/var/log` are being created and owned by root (user and group).
I've written a Nagios check which monitors the log and in order to allow the Nagios user to access it, I gave the `other` group read permissions, that is:

```
chmod o+r /var/log/maillog
```

Now when I think about it, this is only one log file, when the log file will get filled the log rotate mechanism will rename this file and open a new one, but the new `maillog` file will not have the `read write` which I allowed.

So my question is, how can I make sure that the log rotate mechanism will create all the new mailllog files with the right permissions for the Nagios user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`logrotate` has the `create` option:

```
create mode owner group
```

> Immediately after rotation (before the postrotate script is run) the log file is created (with the same name  as  the  log
>                 file  just  rotated).   `mode` specifies the mode for the log file in octal (the same as chmod(2)), owner specifies the user
>                 name who will own the log file, and group specifies the group the log file will belong to. Any of the log file  attributes
>                 may  be omitted, in which case those attributes for the new file will use the same values as the original log file for the
>                 omitted attributes. This option can be disabled using the nocreate option.

More info with `man logrotate`.

Use it like so:

```
/var/log/maillog {
....
        create 664 user group
....
}
```

either in `/etc/logrotate.conf` or a separate file in `/etc/logrotate.d` and check if no other file already overrides this. How this is configured depends on your OS (e.g. on Ubuntu, this is handled in the `rsyslog` configuration).

Comment: How can I configure that only `/var/log/maillog` future log files will be created with the desired user permissions without changing any of the default settings which are already applied to the maillog?

Comment: See my edit and read `man logrotate` (and look into `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d` for lots of examples).

Comment: @ItaiGanot You should also fix your syslog config so that it creates the file with the proper permission, instead of your doing an initial chmod.

Comment: @JennyD, Thanks, that means I should remove the `/var/log/maillog` line from `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` so the settings in `/etc/logrotate.conf` will take place?

Comment: @ItaiGanot No! It means that you should find out what syslog program you're using (probably either `syslog-ng` or `rsyslog`) and change its configuration. This is necessary because when your system is rebooted, or your syslog program is restarted for some other reason, it may re-create the file with the wrong permission.

Comment: But what are the changes that needs to be done?

Comment: @Sven, so as it seems your answer is partial, according to JennyD, doing what you proposed will not be enough, would you like to edit your answer and make it complete? thanks

Comment: Itai, you didn't specify what OS you are on or what syslog daemon you are using. Also, your question was related to `logrotate` and is sufficiently answered - how to configure your local syslog daemon is actually a new question. Quite frankly, this is something you can lookup yourself though - a short google yielded http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_filecreatemode.html as an example.

Comment: It's not even clear that on *your* system the mailer logs through syslog, as you also didn't specify what mailer you are using.

Comment: I understand, I'll ask a new question, thanks for your help again.